# CSX output directory does not exist error

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-cloud-services

Today I suddenly started getting errors when I try to run/debug my Azure cloud project from Visual Studio. I'm running Visual Studio version 15.7.3 and Azure SDK version 2.9.6. The error message says:

> Failed to debug the Microsoft Azure Cloud Service project.  The output
>   directory '\csx\Debug' does not exist.

Yesterday it worked fine, but during the night Windows Update installed some updates and rebooted my machine.

I have tried the following things without success:

- Created the folder myself
- Set full permissions for everyone on the csx folder
- Set full permissions for everyone on the parent folder to the csx folder
- Uninstalled one of the updates which was installed during the night

The strange thing is that if msbuild creates the csx folder without problems, using this command:

```
C:\src\services2>msbuild <cloudproject>.ccproj /p:configuration=debug /maxcpucount /p:outdir="c:\OutDir" /p:overwritereadonlyfiles=true /p:targetprofile="Cloud" /target:Clean;Publish
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with this problem for a long time, I concluded that it was a problem with Visual Studio, since msbuild worked without problems.

After running a "Repair" on Visual Studio, it now works again :-)

You run the repair by selecting Visual Studio from Settings/Apps & features and clicking "Modify":

[image]

In the Visual Studio installer, you then select "Repair":

[image]